# Area Span using python for a collection of points

Tags: python

I have an array for x and y co-ordinates for a set of points.I wanted to estimate the area encompassed by these set of points. Is there any routine for this.

To be more specific --> I have linear growing polymer (set of x,y points) which move laterally. I would like to estimate the area spanned by the polymer through its life time.

Comment: Could you give example points and an area?

Comment: this is similar as generating 1000 points for x and y and want to calculate area compassed by boundary constructed using the outermost points on the x,y plane. I cannot add image here yet.

Comment: Do you mean a [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)?

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I wanted, I was not aware of the name.